# SQL Query to pull only Hard Bounces?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I currently manually update a database by exporting bounced email addresses using the code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(EmailAddress) as EmailAddress, SubscriberKey
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE Status = 'held'
OR Status = 'bounced'
```

We want to change this so we only get hard bounces and can still email addresses with a soft bounce. The BounceCategory column appears to be attributed to another table - how do I update the code?

Apologies if something similar has been asked, I'm brand new to this and very lost.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join up to the _Bounce data view.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(s.EmailAddress) as EmailAddress, 
s.SubscriberKey, 
b.BounceCategory
FROM _Subscribers as s
INNER JOIN _Bounce as b
ON b.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE b.BounceCategory = 'Hard bounce'
```

To add in a column from an additional data extension you can just add another join in the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(s.EmailAddress) as EmailAddress, 
s.SubscriberKey, 
b.BounceCategory,
bh.PROMO_KEY
FROM _Subscribers as s
INNER JOIN _Bounce as b
ON b.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
INNER JOIN BounceHeld as bh
ON bh.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE b.BounceCategory = 'Hard bounce'
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. 

I hate to ask another question here but I just learned we need to bring in a custom field from a data extension. Field is PROMO_KEY from an extension called "BounceHeld" and I'm not sure how to incorporate. Would you be able to help? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok so you have a DE called BounceHeld with a column called PROMO_KEY. Is that the only field in the Data Extension? You will need a subscriber key or email or something that will be used to join the data together.

Comment: The DE also has EmailAddress, SubscriberKey and BounceCategory.

Comment: @L.Tracy, I have updated my answer with a query that should work for you. Keep in mind that the query will only include subscribers that are in all locations (INNER JOIN), _Subscribers, _Bounce and the BounceHeld DE, which is what I have assumed is your use case.